# Wordpress Hooks not setting the constructor data

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am making a logging sdk. The code I used in my plugin main file where the sdk starts is

```
function rpt_wpb()
            {
                global $rpt_wpb;

                if (!isset($rpt_wpb)) {
                    // Include  SDK.
                    // print_r(RELATED_POSTS_THUMBNAILS_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/wpb-sdk/require.php');exit;
                    require_once RELATED_POSTS_THUMBNAILS_PLUGIN_DIR . '/lib/wpb-sdk/require.php';
                    $rpt_wpb = new Logger(
                        array(
                            'id'    => 7,
                            'name'  => 'Related Posts Thumbnails Plugin for WordPress',
                            'slug' => 'related-posts-thumbnails',
                            'type' => 'plugin',
                            'path'  => __FILE__,
                            'version'   => RELATED_POSTS_THUMBNAILS_VERSION,
                            'public_key' => '7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a691462a815',
                            'is_premium' => false,
                            'has_addons' => false,
                            'has_paid_plans' => false,
                            'menu' => array()
                        )
                    );
                }

                return $rpt_wpb;
            }

            // Init .
            rpt_wpb();

            do_action('rpt_wpb_loaded');
        }
```

Then is my logger class where I am using a constructor to get the data that is logged from the class initialization in plugin main file. And inside the constructor I am using a function that call up all the hooks (dynamic_init()).

```
public function __construct($product_data)
    {
        // print_r($product_data);exit;
        self::$product_data = $product_data;
        // echo "<pre>";print_r(self::$product_data);exit;
        $this->dynamic_init();
    }

    /**
     * Call wp hooks to initialize logger actions.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function dynamic_init()
    {   
        // $product_data = self::$product_data;
        // echo "<pre> Product Data: ";print_r($product_data);exit;
        add_action('init', array($this, 'set_logs_schedule'));
        add_action('wpb_logger_cron_' . self::$product_data['slug'], array($this, 'log_plugin'));
        add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'deactivation_model'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_wpb_sdk_' . self::$product_data['slug'] . '_deactivation', array($this, 'ajax_deactivation'));

        register_activation_hook(self::$product_data['path'], array(__CLASS__, 'log_activation'));
        register_deactivation_hook(self::$product_data['path'], array(__CLASS__, 'product_deactivation'));
        register_uninstall_hook(self::$product_data['path'], array(__CLASS__, 'log_uninstallation'));
    }
```

Now the main issue is that in below functions

```
public function set_logs_schedule()
    {   
        // print_r(self::$product_data['slug']);exit;

        if (!wp_next_scheduled('wpb_logger_cron_' . self::$product_data['slug'])) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'weekly', 'wpb_logger_cron_' . self::$product_data['slug']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add deactivation model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function deactivation_model()
    {
        // print_r((self::$product_data['slug']));exit;

        if (function_exists('get_current_screen')) {

            $screen = get_current_screen();

            if ('plugins.php' === $screen->parent_file) {
        
                $product_slug = self::$product_data['slug'];
                $product_name = self::$product_data['name'];
                $has_pro_version = (in_array($product_slug, self::$has_pro_version)) ? true : false;

                include dirname(__DIR__) . '/views/wpb-sdk-deactivate-form.php';
            }
        }
    }
```

The product_data of the plugin is not coming instead the data of last plugin in the list that contains sdk comes up.

I expect that the data of product_data should come up in set_logs_schedule() and deactivation_model(). Moreover I am new in wordpress plugin development so that's why I am struggling.

Comment: "where I am using a constructor to get the data that is logged from the class initialization in plugin main file" -- none of your other code you posted uses `rpt_wpb` to fetch the product data. Why do you assume `$product_data` will contain it?

Comment: @soulseekah thats only for calling that class and making its object

Comment: You did not answer the question. Where is `$product_data` coming from, what does it contain?

Comment: from the main file new Logger($rpoduct_data) is coming

Comment: You've provided the code where you define the logger and create it, but have yet to show where you're trying to use it. I don't see a problem, show the code.

Comment: the problem is in logger. The code I pass in new logger(array()) is not been fetched in add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'deactivation_model'));
  add_action('wp_ajax_wpb_sdk_' . self::$product_data['slug'] . '_deactivation', array($this, 'ajax_deactivation'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're new to creating classes in php you should avoid using `self::` because it refers to static class variables and methods. The way they behave is intricate and non-intuitive. Instead use instance variables. That is, say things like

```
$this->product_data
```

rather than

```
self::$product_data
```

and your code will be more predictable in what it does.

And, use a decent IDE with code formatting and error detection. Code readability counts for a lot.

Comment: @O.JonesI am using $product_data as static variable